# $\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin(x))$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

From this paper: http://math.ucsd.edu/~ebender/20B/7_DefInt.pdf
 [image]

Shouldn't $du$ be $dt$? And also how do you get from that line to the final result if $du$ is not $dt$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be $dt$ and not $du$.  The final line is merely a consequence of the fact that $$\int_{x=a}^b f(x) \, dx + \int_{x=b}^c f(x) \, dx = \int_{x=a}^c f(x) \, dx$$ for $a \le b \le c$.